# NFS stale mountpoint error

Tags: linux, nfs

How to check nfs stale mount error on linux ,
Do I need to cd to the  mountpoint and do ls to check output as 
?---------  ? ?       ?             ?            ?

Is there any file where it gets captured or does it prompts on df -h output ?

Comment: You need to check that the server is still exporting that filesystem and that the server still grants permission to this client. Check the server's `/etc/exports` for a start.

Comment: I have a task to scan all my linux server probably 100 and see if any nfs shares on them become stale nfs ? If I get to know to check stale nfs error on one hosts(quickest way), i can create a script to scan all 100 server

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood the question, sorry. What about just `df`? Doesn't that show errors for stale NFS mount points?

Comment: I wanted to see how stale nfs error looks like.I have seen files timestamp  going to ?---?.      What error it says on df output ? Does it display stale messages or file size goes to - - - - ?

Comment: Those question marks are just `ls` saying it could not obtain the necessary information. The actual error message is separate and just about any tool should output it, from `ls` to `df` or even `rm`. It's a standard error code `ESTALE`, usually shown as "`Stale NFS file handle`".

Comment: does this error messages Stale NFS file handle visible in /var/log/messages ?

Comment: Only if something like a daemon tries to access the filesystem and obtains that error and if that daemon happens to log errors in that location. The error is in fact reported through whatever channels whatever program received the error usually reports errors. For interactive commands, that would usually be the command's stderr, most likely your terminal. For daemons, it could be syslog. But a program is also free to report the error nowhere if it wants to.

Comment: You haven't answered my question as to whether errors reported by `df` are enough for you. Because running `df` on 100 machines seems like a good enough way to me to perform your audit. And if you aren't sure how the error would be reported by `df`, simulate it on a test server and see what happens!